# Algorithm to find word on Boggle board

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, boggle

I'm building a boggle game in vb .net. Right now, my dices are as a 2d array (0,0 0,1 ) etc...

What I want it to do is, as I'm typing the word, that it highlights it on the board using the `button(x,y).doclick` sub which highlights it. Right now my implementation finds the first letter, then keeps trying each letter until it meets the 8 corner condition (ie it is neighbored to  the last one) but this does not always work. If there are say 2 "G"'s on the board and I want the bottom one, this will not work. Can somebody give me an example of psuedocode of what needs to happen. I've been stumped for almost 6 hours trying to figure this out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, given a string you want to highlight one path through the dice that matches the string. Sometimes there are several possible choices, so adding a letter may completely change what is highlighted. It may be a good approach here to keep results from the previous substring, so we don't have to start over. Then a reasonable thing to do would be to compute all possible paths.

The answer for a given string s would be a list of paths, where a path is a list of grid coordinates. Each path is something you could reasonably highlight, so you just highlight the first one. When adding a letter to the string, you find paths you can expand and remove the ones you can't expand.

I'm afraid I don't know how to write vb code. Since you asked for pseudocode, here's some rough python-like pseudocode instead. I'm coding the boggle grid as a list of 16 items. The neighbors(x) function returns a list of the neighboring positions (except for edge cases that's going to be [x-1, x+1, x-4, x+4]).

```
def firstLetter(typed):
  answer = []
  for pos in range(16): if grid[pos]==typed: answer += [pos]
  return answer

def addletter(partialanswer, typed):
  answer2 = []
  for partial in partialanswer:
      for neighbor in neighbors(partial[-1]):
          if grid[neighbor]==typed: 
             # partial+[neighbor] is a list. answer2 is a list of such lists.
             answer2 += partial + [neighbor]
  return answer2
```

If the player types "go", for example, then
(a) player types "g", code calls firstletter("g") and gets a list "answer" of the positions in the grid that have a "g" in them. Highlight, say, the first one.
(b) player types "o", code calls addletter(answer, "o") and gets a list of the paths in the grid that say "go". Again, highlight the first one.